# How to add an individual, six datatypes properties, and rules for a reasoner?

Tags: java, jena, owl, protege

I have an RDF ontology file created with Protégé 4.3, and I'm trying to create a Java application (using Netbeans and Jena) to add a new individual with six datatype properties. How can I add this individual, and add rules to the reasoner and do inference?  My initial code is:

```java
package transportevaluation;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

    /**
     *
     * @author sara
     */
    public class TransportEvaluation {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // create an empty model

            Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

            String inputFileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Protege_4.3\\Evaluation\\Evaluation.owl";
            // use the FileManager to find the input file
            InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName );
            if (in == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFileName
                        + " not found");
            }

            model.read(in, "", "RDF/XML");

            // write it to standard out
            model.write(System.out);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please provide us with a starting point so we can help you.

Comment: My departure point is an RDF files that describe my ontology.

Comment: @user3333358 I expect that TomFenech meant "please show us some data" and probably something like the URI of the individual you want to create, the properties and values you want to add, etc.

Comment: For exemple: Individual SCNTRI ; Type Transport System; with datatype properties: NbStations 51; NbAbsence 12; NbDelays 12; TimeBetweenSuccessiveTravel 12; NbAccident 12.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend beginning with reading [this resource](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/) on Jena inference. Other resources within the Jena documentation will be quite useful, such as this one on the [Ontology API](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) or

The following code snippet will give you a rule-based reasoner, populated with your ontology, and an individual which you can test inference with. If you are uncertain how to set/get properties in Jena, then you may wish to start with an [Introduction to the Jena API](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html)

```
final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
model.read( yourInputSource );

model.createIndividual("x-test://someTestIRI");
// TODO add whatever properties are necessary to trigger inference
// TODO test whatever properties are necessary to verify inference occured
```

If you need to engage in non-owl rule-based reasoning, and need to construct your own rules, then the Jena Inference link above will be the best starting point.